# When using cosine rule on an obtuse angle do we take the negative or positive cosine value?

Tags: trigonometry

Cosine rule states $A^2=B^2+C^2-BC\cos(a)$

Now when a is an obtuse angle $\cos(a)$ is a negative value. Do we use the negative cosine value or take its positive?

Comment: If we wanted to take the positive value the formula would be $A^2=B^2+C^2-BC|\cos a|$ where $|\circ|$ denotes the absolute value.

Answer (score 3):

We take the cosine of $a$. It's as simple as that.